# Collecting messages which are not successfully written on Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am reading a file and dumping each record on Kafka. Here is my producer code:

```
public void produce(String topicName, String filePath, String bootstrapServers, String encoding) {
     try (BufferedReader bf = getBufferedReader(filePath, encoding);
                 KafkaProducer<Object, String> producer = initKafkaProducer(bootstrapServers)) {
                String line;
                long count = 0;
                while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
                    count++;
                    producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(topicName, line), (metadata, e) -> {
                        if(e != null){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            //write record to some file.
                        }
                    });
                }
                producer.flush();
                CustomLogger.log("Done producing data messages. Total no of records produced:" + count);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Throwables.propagate(e);
            }
}
 private static KafkaProducer<Object, String> initKafkaProducer(String bootstrapServer) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("bootstrap.servers", bootstrapServer);
        properties.put("key.serializer", StringSerializer.class.getCanonicalName());
        properties.put("value.serializer", StringSerializer.class.getCanonicalName());
        properties.put("acks", "-1");
        properties.put("retries", 4);
        return new KafkaProducer<>(properties);
    }

private BufferedReader getBufferedReader(String filePath, String encoding) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, FileNotFoundException {
    return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filePath), Optional.ofNullable(encoding).orElse("UTF-8")));
}
```

As per our basic tests there are chances that producing message can fail due to TimeoutException. However as per the [official documentation of Callback](https://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/Callback.html) TimeoutException is a retriable exception. Means in next retries this message might get produced. Hence I can not consider that record sending is failed if I find TimeoutException in callback. Is there any realiable way using which I can surely say that record sending is failed and log that in separate file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a brief look at the code and don't think, that you need to distinguish between retriable and non-retriable exceptions here, as this already happens in KafkaProducer.

When you configure the producer with a *retries* value of larger than 1, it will resend any message (batch) that failed with a retriable exception as many times as you told it to, before returning the exception to you.

So basically, any message you get back with an exception the producer has given up on.

Have a look at [completeBatch](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/internals/Sender.java#L294) & [canRetry](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/internals/Sender.java#L330) in the code to confirm my understanding, but personally I think this behavior makes sense.